# How can i post a DTO that contain an array of entities?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a couple of questions about NestJS and TypeOrm.
First, how to pass an array of strings to DTO? I tried just to use :string[] type, but the compiler gives an error.
This is my Post entity:

```
@Entity('posts')
export class Post {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.posts, { cascade: true })
    author: number;

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp' })
    date: Date;

    @Column()
    text: string;
    
    @Column({ default: 0 })
    likes: number;

    @OneToMany(() => Photo, photo => photo.post, { cascade: true })
    photos: Photo[];
}
```

And CreatePostDto:

```
export class CreatePostDto {
    authorId: number;
    date: Date;
    text?: string;
    // photos?: string[];
}
```

And the second question: How can i save to the repository every photo (keeping the connection with post), posts to the posts repo and update user by adding new post binded to him.
I tried something like this, but it won't work obviously.

```
    async create(createPostDto: CreatePostDto) {
      const post = this.postsRepository.create(createPostDto);
      const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne(createPostDto.authorId);
      
      return this.postsRepository.save({author: user, date: createPostDto.date, text: createPostDto.text});
  }
```

Comment: are the photos already saved in the database? what is the content of the photos array will be?can you share photo entity?

Comment: @Youba, no, photos are created too. The content of photos array will be the string. Array of strings (urls). I already found a solution, but don't know how correct is it:

https://prnt.sc/wi6d1p

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missed here is saving photos before bind them with the post, here's an example:

```
async create(createPostDto: CreatePostDto) {
 let photos:Array<Photo> = [] ; array of type photo entity
   for(let urlPhoto of createPostDto.photos)
   {
    let  photo =  await this.imageRepository.save({url : urlPhoto }); you must save the photos first
    photos.push(photo); 
   }
  const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne(createPostDto.authorId);
  
  return this.postsRepository.save({author: user, date: createPostDto.date, text: 
   createPostDto.text,photos:photos});
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me, but image's postId is null. How can i pass the post object to the photo before Post initialization? (my post entity has url and post: PostEntity)

Comment: can you share the photo entity?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wi7619 
Sorry for the link. Can't send the formatted code.

Comment: Wait, everything works nice. I used forEach instead of for (let ... of ..). Thank you!

Comment: good luck, next time try to edit your post with the code asked for it's better to make a screenshot,

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column("simple-array")
    names: string[]
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This is not an entity array. And as far as I know, not every database supports array types. The answer is to map the array DTO and save every entity with a connection to its parent.